# Sublime-Package: 'No SSL support included in this Python' when try to send a mail python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, sublimetext3

Try to create a package in **sublime-text3** that use to send mail to team members.

> Python3 script work fine when try to run this on command-line interpreter but throw exception when use script in Package class (No SSL support included in this Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the **SSL package (SSL for linux)** using Package Control. Then restart sublime.
And if you are missing Package Control then open up the console (CTRL+`) and paste in the code from [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3), then hit Enter.

Comment: Did you read the page where you got that code? It very clearly says to **not** post the code elsewhere, as it changes with each release of Package Control. Instead, link to the page itself.